# Where is the local repository located?

Tags: git

From [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Git_data_flow_simplified.svg):

[image]

Where is said "Local repository" located **physically** (in the file system)?

Comment: I just like your ID today.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The Working Directory is wherever your files are on your local machine. The Local Repository is the `.git/` subdirectory inside the Working Directory. The Index is a conceptual place that also physically resides in the `.git/` subdirectory.

Comment: I think people very frequently use "repository" to refer to the combination of work tree and .git directory (though that's not how it's used in the diagram in the question).

Comment: @Greg Hewgill Oops... I was totally confused by the new terminology. Thanks for correcting this misconception. +1. I am taking this opportunity to also thank the so many who pointed out my misconception.

Comment: By default .git directory is hidden inside working directory in windows.

Comment: @Cascabel, so is it technically correct to say 'Github online repository' to mean the source code files there ? Why?

Answer (score 7):

Working directory is your code directory

Local repository is .git folder in Working directory

Remote repository is bare repository on server or in the filesystem

Answer (score 4):

.git is a place where local repository is stored (not the working directory!)

Working directory usually is a directory where the .git directory is placed

Answer (score 1):

Working Directory is where your code resides on local machine.
Git Local repo is .git/  which is generally inside the Working Directory.
It contains HEAD and various useful info.
You can have a look of what it contains:

```
cd .git 
ls -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Uttams-MBP:project uttamgc$ ls -al

drwxr-xr-x  9 uttamgc  staff  288 Sep 28 14:19 .git

In the example above, project is the folder or directory [mkdir] once this folder is created I move into project directory [cd project] then I git init from the folder and create .git subdirectory. [the third row with .git is the local repository]